# В чем минусы шифрования каждой записи базы данных sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нашел мнение о том что лучше шифровать всю бд и при шифровании видны некоторые метаданные. Про какие метаданные идет речь, и что мне делать(Я уже создал программу, которая шифрует каждую запись)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите.

Вот вы зашифровали каждую запись в базе.

А теперь у вас возникла проблема: как бы найти записи, в котрых содержится текст "президент бомба".

С незашифрованной базой прокатил бы простой SQL запрос

`SELECT * FROM records WHERE record_text LIKE '%президент%' AND record_text LIKE '%бомба%'`

А если все записи зашифрованы - то для поиска нужно вытащить все записи, каждую из них расшифровать и потом уже проверить на наличие требуемых слов.

И так будет происходить при любой попытке работать с базой.

То есть, проще говоря, сила базы =- именно в том, что к её записям можно обращаться неким единообразным способом (SQL - запросы).

Если это преимущество у базы отнять, зашифровав записи (ну, на зашифрованных, особенно хорошо зашифрованных записях sql - запросы бессмысленны), то преимущества базы исчезают, и можно с тем же успехом использовать plain file, содержащий зашифрованные данные.

В "промышленной эксплуатации" иногда применяют такой способ, когда "вся база зашифрована, а записи в ней - не зашифрованы": помещаем базу в зашифрованный контейнер, например, том vera crypt. Как только ввели ключ (или пароль) - контейнер расшифровался, его примонтировали и с базой можно работать. Как с незашифрованной, со всеми преимуществами простой базы данных.

Как только пришли грабители (или наоборот, милиционеры) - быстренько том размонтировали, и он превратился в массив псевдо - случайных данных.

Преимущество этого способа еще и в том, что Вам самому не надо реализовывать шифрование (это весьма нелёгкое и очень тонкое занятие): шифрование берет на себя готовая утилита, а секретность обеспечивается набором ключей.

Answer (score 3):

Если шифровать только записи, то структура базы и таблиц очевидна. А это дает большой простор для исследований.

Плюс, так как каждая запись шифруется отдельно, то сила шифра сильно ухудшается - ведь теперь есть большой набор шифрованных данных, значение некоторых из них вполне можно и восстановить - Если поле содержит int или короткую строку (к примеру имя страны), то тут все сильно-сильно упрощается. А вот для программиста только усложняется.

Если же шифруется вся база, то дешифровка усложняется. Хотя в этом случае всегда можно попытаться поймать момент, когда вся таблица расшифрована в памяти сдампить. Но если утекла сама база - то дешифровать будет сложнее. Хотя, можно использовать тот факт, что первые байты файла базы достаточно предсказуемые:)

Answer (score 2):

Лишь добавлю к предыдущим ответам. Что шифрованные данных в базе используют только для работы с ними из вне, сама СУБД превращается тупо в хранилище. Никаких более или менее операций с этими данными СУБД не сможет реализовать только базовые select/update/insert/delete - никаких там тебе поисков, вычислений .... К примеру пароли давно уже хешируют что бы не восстанавливать вовсе. Сила всех субд это работа с данными, а шифрование превращает субд не известно во что