# шифрование при запи данных в бд и дешиврование при выводе данных

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

собственно сабж, как правильно сделать такой механизм? т.е. все что попадает в базу надо шифровать и все что селектится из базы надо дешифровать обратно. Да есть механизмы самого СУБД в моем случае Постгрес но до меня уже на уровне языка сделали и надо оптимизировать т.к. там все фильды по отдельности шифруются и потом в базу отправляются

Comment: Отлично. Вот у Вас пара {Id, Name}. Вы зашифровали имя перед записью в базу данных. а потом надо выполнить запрос "where Name like '%Вася%'". Как его выполнить с зашифрованными данными? почитайье вот это обсуждение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1175639/

Comment: да правильно говорите но такая требования, а при поиске лайк не используется и без точной инфы поиск не будет работать. Но задача такая что нужно шифровать при записи и наоборот при выводе

Answer (score 0):

решил используя AttributeConverter